# What is wrong with my removeBack function?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I made a linked list, and my other functions work, but my removeBack doesn't. I traverse through the nodes checking if they are NULL, if the node is NULL I copy the linker to the previous pointer which points to the second to last and delete the node that contains the NULL value. I was sure this worked, until two numbers that were supposed to be deleted don't get deleted. Here is my code. Can someone guide me here?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node * next;
};

class linkedList
{
private:
    node * head;

public:
    linkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
void addFront(int x)
{
    node * babynode = new node;

    //(*babynode).data = x;
    babynode->data = x;

    babynode->next = head;
    head = babynode;
}

void display()
{
    node * finger = head;

    while( finger != NULL )
    {
        cout << finger->data << endl;
        finger = finger->next;
    }
}

//remove and return the first item in the list
void removeFront()
{

    if(head != NULL)
    {
    node * front = head;
    head = head->next;
    delete front;
    }
    else
    {
        head = NULL;
    }

}

void addBack(int x)
{   
    node * tail = head;
    //only if head is empty
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        addFront(x);
    }
    //if it isnt empty
    else{

        while(tail->next != NULL)
        {
            tail = tail->next;
        }           
            node * tail2 = new node;
            tail2 -> data = x;

            tail2 -> next = tail -> next;
            tail -> next = tail2;
        }
    }

void removeBack()
{   
    node * one = head;
    node * two = one -> next;
while(two != NULL)
{
    if(two == NULL)
    {
        delete one;
        head -> next = two;
    }
    one = one -> next;
    two = one -> next;
    }
}

};
```

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "myLinkedList.h"

int main()
{
    linkedList mylist;

    //Step 1:
    //Implement insertion to the front or the back of the list
    mylist.addBack(2);
    mylist.addBack(3);

    mylist.addFront(5);
    mylist.addFront(7);

    mylist.addBack(11);
    mylist.addBack(13);
    mylist.addBack(17);

    mylist.addFront(19);
    mylist.addFront(23);

    mylist.display(); //23 19 7 5 2 3 11 13 17

    //Step 2: 
    //Implement removal of the first or last item
    mylist.removeFront();
    mylist.removeFront();
    mylist.removeBack();
    mylist.removeBack();

    mylist.addFront(29);
    mylist.addBack(31);
    mylist.addBack(37);
    mylist.addBack(41);

    mylist.display(); //29 7 5 2 3 11 31 37 41

    ////Step 3:
    ////Implement a tricimation routine
    //mylist.tricmate(); //delete every 3rd item
    //mylist.display(); //29 7 2 3 31 37

    ////Step 4:
    ////Implement a find and remove method
    //mylist.remove(3);
    //mylist.remove(29);
    //mylist.remove(37);

    //mylist.addFront(43);
    //mylist.addBack(47);

    //mylist.display(); //43 7 2 31 47

    ////Step 5: sort!
    //mylist.sort();
    //mylist.display(); //2 7 31 43 47

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes; the next step is to crack open the debugger and do some debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> What is wrong with my removeBack function?

Here's what I see:

```
void removeBack()
{   
   node * one = head;
   node * two = one -> next; // When the list is empty, this
                             // will result in undefined behavior.
   while(two != NULL)
   {
      if(two == NULL) // This is never true.
                      // You've already checked in the while
                      // statement that two != NULL.
                      // Hence, you never end up deleting the item
                      // at the back of the list.
      {
         delete one;
         head -> next = two;
      }
      one = one -> next;
      two = one -> next;
   }
}
```

This should work:

```
void removeBack()
{   
   // First, check whether the list is empty
   if ( head == NULL )
   {
      return;
   }

   // Next, check whether there is only one item
   if ( head->next == NULL )
   {
      delete head;
      head = NULL;
      return;
   }

   // Now for the rest...
   // iterate to get to the end.
   node * iter = head;
   while ( iter->next->next != NULL )
   {
      iter = iter -> next;
   }

   delete iter->next;
   iter->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: this worked, but I had to modify it, because we're not allowed to use ->next->next;

Comment: @SamPerales, that's a strange requirement. Oh well. As long as you got a working solution, it's all good.